# review comport code in wince 6.0

Tags: windows-ce

hellou all, we have ibutton devices for reading ibutton. This device is usb and have FTDI virtual comport.

We have our simple aplication for reading data from reader, but reader have problem (when is more buttons swipe on reader - it stop send data) 
In this case when we catch problem (sending G and g - like green diode stop and start), restart comport - but after reboot comport aplication takes 100% of cpu.

is here anybody which have any idea what we need to do or how modify source code.
thanks a lot

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using OpenNETCF;

namespace SerialDownload
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddLog("Vytvaram novy seriovy port");

            serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM4";
            serialPort1.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
            serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
            //serialPort1.ErrorReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_ErrorReceived);
            //serialPort1.PinChanged += new System.IO.Ports.SerialPinChangedEventHandler(serialPort1_PinChanged);
            serialPort1.WriteBufferSize = 10000;
            serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 2000;
            AddLog("Vytvoreny seriovy port");
        }
        bool zelena = false;
        private void timerResetCOM_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            timerResetCOM.Enabled = false;

            if (!nacitavam_kartu_serial)
            {
                try
                {

                    string znak = "G";
                    if (!zelena)
                    {
                        znak = "g";
                        zelena = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        zelena = false;
                    }

                    AddLog("Posielam " + znak);
                    serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 2000;
                    serialPort1.Write(znak);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                    AddLog("Odoslane " + znak);

                }
                catch
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                    AddLog("Chyba serioveho portu pri odoslani G");
                    try
                    {
                        serialPort1.DataReceived -= serialPort1_DataReceived;
                        AddLog("robim discard");
                        serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                        AddLog("Discard dokonceny");
                        AddLog("Zatvaram port");
                        serialPort1.Close();
                        AddLog("port zatvoreny");

                        KillProc("SerialDownload");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                        AddLog("Chyba zatorenia portu");

                    }

                    /*
                    try
                    {

                        AddLog("Dispose serioveho");
                        serialPort1.DataReceived -= serialPort1_DataReceived;


                        serialPort1.Dispose();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

                        AddLog("Dispose serioveho OK");

                        AddLog("Vytvaram novy seriovy port");

                        serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
                        serialPort1.PortName = "COM4";
                        serialPort1.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
                        serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
                        //serialPort1.ErrorReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_ErrorReceived);
                        //serialPort1.PinChanged += new System.IO.Ports.SerialPinChangedEventHandler(serialPort1_PinChanged);
                        serialPort1.WriteBufferSize = 10000;
                        serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
                        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
                        serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 2000;
                        serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 2000;
                        AddLog("Vytvoreny seriovy port");

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        AddLog("Chyba vytvaranie serioveho portu - alebo rusenia");
                    }
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    try
                    {
                        AddLog("otvaram port");
                        serialPort1.Open();

                        serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
                        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
                        serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 2000;
                        serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 2000;
                        AddLog("port otvoreny");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                        AddLog("Chyba otvorenia portu");
                    }*/
                }
            }

        }
        bool nacitavam_kartu_serial = false;

        private void KillProc(string name)
        {
            var processes = OpenNETCF.ToolHelp.ProcessEntry.GetProcesses();

            foreach (OpenNETCF.ToolHelp.ProcessEntry process in processes)
            {
                if (name == process.ExeFile)
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddLog(string riadok)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss") + ": " + riadok);
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            nacitavam_kartu_serial = true;
            AddLog("Nacitacam data");
            try
            {
                string pStrTmp = string.Empty;
                while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    pStrTmp += (char)serialPort1.ReadByte();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
                }


                string card_id_t = pStrTmp;

                AddLog("Nacitane data: " + card_id_t);

                StreamWriter subor = File.CreateText("\\NAND\\karta_serial.txt");
                subor.Write(card_id_t);
                subor.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AddLog(ex.Message);
            }
            nacitavam_kartu_serial = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you have `serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;`. Shouldn't that be `serialPort1.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);`?

Comment: Another comment is about the `ReadByte` then `Sleep` commands. Possibly the communication channel is getting crammed full of data. I'd remove the Sleep and debug or use `ReadLine` (which is how we use RS232 ports in our Win CE 6.0 app).

Answer (score 0):

It is late, but I will leave my answer here.
I have seen similar problem with .NET Compact Framework and com port, two years ago. The device I had was on windows mobile 6, the other device was BT printer on comport.

Other handheld devices ran just fine, just this one had exactly the same problem, when you turn of the printer - the app ran slow, to the point where you could not use it for work anymore.

My temporal solution was to close the SerialPort object.

I hope it helps